# Atom text editor remove trailing whitespace on save

Tags: save, whitespace, sublimetext3, removing-whitespace, atom-editor

I use `Sublime text`. Now I am trying `Atom`. When I save any file in sublime text it does not include any trailing blank line. But saving any file in `Atom` leaves a trailing blank line. How do I force `Atom` not to leave trailing white spaces?

Comment: Atom sticks to POSIX definition of a line by default:  
`"A sequence of zero or more non- <newline> characters plus a terminating <newline> character."` 
— https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Under your Atom `Preferences` go to `Packages` tab and search for `whitespace`. Click on the `whitespace` package and uncheck `Ensure Single Trailing Newline` option

[image]

Comment: I think its even better if we unckeck "Ignore whitespace On current line". This will remove the trailing whitespace of current line at the time when file is saved.

Comment: Could this message get any more cryptic? Lol - I'm just over-joyed to have Atom mangle a long file's diff because another dev left some trailing spaces only to find that it is not possible to find this setting by name.  Few..  Anyone notice that the name changed from Package to Settings?

Comment: Maybe this is a new setting, but there is a `Remove Trailing Whitespace` checkbox at the bottom of the `settings` section. Unchecking it preserves all trailing whitespaces.

Comment: File --> Settings --> Packages

Answer (score 21):

On global level this can be changed using `settings` in `Whitespace` package, but if you want to disable it for a specific language you have to use syntax-scoped properties in your config.cson.

```
'.text.html.php': # php overrides
  whitespace:
    ensureSingleTrailingNewline: false
    removeTrailingWhitespace: false

'.source.ruby': # ruby overrides
  whitespace:
    ensureSingleTrailingNewline: false
    removeTrailingWhitespace: false
```

To see the scope of language go to `Packages` tab and search for your language.

[image]

Click on the settings of the language package and you can see the scope:

[image]

Comment: Your answer is even more detailed than the official docs at https://github.com/atom/whitespace, thanks for taking the time to put this up! :-) I would love to configure atom this way, but I can't get it to work, atom keeps turning two trailing newlines into a single one in my jinja2 files. Scope is `.text.html.jinja`, config matches yours, but doesn't work. Global it is then :-(

Comment: The image showing how to find the scope was particularly useful. I've since also found the scopes listed in the grammar selector (by default to the right of the line endings, line number and encoding at the bottom of the window, or with the default shortcut `ctrl+shift+L`).

Answer (score 11):

Go to packages and find "whitespace", go to it's settings and uncheck the last checkbox.

**Settings**
[image: Settings screenshot]

**Checkbox**
[image: Checkbox screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Dan Moldavan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30403353/10907864).

I experienced this issue when working on a Rails Application.

I added a `.editorconfig` file with the following properties:

```
# editorconfig.org

root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
indent_size = 2
indent_style = space
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

And I added a `.gitattributes` file with the following properties:

```
# Enforce Unix newlines
* text=auto eol=lf
```

And then my Atom Editor threw a problem:

> 1 problem affecting .gitattributes

> whitespace: It is possible that the "whitespace"-package prevents the following properties from working reliably: insert_final_newline, trim_trailing_whitespace. You may try reconfiguring or disabling the "whitespace"-package to solve regarding issues.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

- Open your Atom Editor
- Go to Edit > Preferences > Packages
- Type in whitespace
- Click on the package that shows up
- Untick the following:

  - **Ensure Single Trailing Newline**
  - **Ignore Whitespace On Current Line**
- Leave **Ignore Whitespace Only Lines** unticked

[image: Screenshot of the fix]

Save and close the settings.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Do you have any idea how hard it is to read your screenshot? Us a dark theme in your own work if you must, but a light theme makes a much more readable image.